# Vertically align across multirow cells in a table

Tags: tables

The [following code](http://pastebin.com/8Z1pMBNp) (pastebin - large block of hard-to-read text, open in a proper text editor and disable word wrap to make it display properly) produces the following image:

[image: The resultant table]

My question seems simple, but the solutions I have found online does not seem to work: How do I make the text in the first two columns align vertically to the middle?

Comment: You can do that using `multirow` for the 1st column, but counting the number of lines, and not the number of rows. For instance, for ‘reliability’, I would use `\multirow{3}{*}{Reliability}`, plus some manual adjustment to take linethickness into account. Also the `m{width}` column type  instead of `p{width}`. For aesthetic reasons, I also would use the `booktabs` package and no vertical rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want that “Scalability” is hanging somewhere in the middle of white space. In all tables, a blank cell means repetition of the above value.

You should also avoid vertical rules that hinder rather than ease legibility.

Here's an implementation of your table in a rotated fashion (but this is not really necessary, you decide if it's the case of centering it in the margins at the cost of reducing the size of the middle column).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,array,rotating}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{The ATAM Attribute Utility Tree}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9.5cm} @{} }
\toprule
\bfseries\splitcell{Quality \\ Attribute}
  & \bfseries\splitcell{Attribute \\ Refinement}
  & \bfseries Scenarios \\
\midrule
Reliability
  & Fatal error recovery
  & Mechanisms must be in place to ensure any error that occurs is handled without
    causing the application to crash.
\\\addlinespace
  & Reliable Simulation
  & Calculate physics simulation results in a reliable manner.
\\
\midrule
Scalability
  & Scale with world size and complexity
  & Physical world size and complexity will have an impact on graphics hardware performance. 
    The resource requirements must scale linearly with the complexity of the graphical assets 
    on screen.
\\\addlinespace
  & Scale with vehicle complexity
  & System performance will be affected by the increase in vehicle complexity. The resources 
    requirements must scale in proportion to the complexity size.
\\\addlinespace
  & Scale with multiplayer size
  & On the multiplayer server side, the amount of concurrent connections into the 
    server is going to impact performance. Servers must have a known budget and resources 
    requirements must be known for concurrent connection sizes.
\\
\midrule
Performance
  & Consistent performance
  & Maintain framerate as simulation complexity grows.
\\
\midrule
Maintainability
  & Core isolation
  & Update core physics engine without affecting other parts
\\\addlinespace
  & Pluggable rendering engine
  & Different rendering engines (Direct3D, OpenGL, Mantle etc.)\ should be used 
    depending on architecture and user requirements.
\\
\midrule
Flexibility
  & Simulation Flexibility
  & Simulate various types of vehicles such as cars, boats and aircraft with same
    simulation engine.
\\\addlinespace
  & Scriptable Interface to Simulation
  & Read vehicle configurations and simulation parameters in from human readable files.
\\
\midrule
Configurability
  & System Settings
  & Capacity for various translations (and possible future translations) must be
    available in the architecture.
\\\addlinespace
  & Scenario Settings
  & Adjustable scenario parameters such as weather conditions, time of day, terrain
    conditions and various triggerable events must be accessible from the interface.
\\
\midrule
Internationalisation
  & Local Translation
  & System settings such as audio, graphics and interface must be settable from the
    interface and changes must be persistent.
\\\addlinespace
  & Unit Translations
  & Units must be displayable in various formats such as imperial and ISO.
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Note that the various blocks are separated with `\midrule`, while different items in the same blocks are separated with `\addlinespace`.

[image]

Comment: Although your post did not quite answer my question, I took your advice to heard and used your answer in my final product. Thanks!

Comment: @getack I don't think there is a real answer to your question, other than “fix the position manually by trial and error” or, perhaps, with some complex macro where you feed the texts in the third column for every block and measure it.